# Rails - Remote link created with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using remote link with rails successfully, just using `link_to ... :remote => true`.

My problem comes when I create links with javascript, some of my links are created by a javascript event and don't know how to turn them as remote links.

I've tried to set `data-remote="true"` but it doesn't work, I think that's because my links are created with events, and data-remote links are created during onload.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Rails should handle the links `<a data-remote='true'`, even if they're inserted via javascript after page loading. Check there is no javascript error when you insert the link into the document or when you click on the link.

Comment: In fact, I've found that the div where I add the link has a `e.preventDefault` which seems to be the problem, I can't change that because the div is generated by a javascript library. I'm able to bind a click event directly to my link but don't know what to bind..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I simply use `$.get` instead of trying to use a data-remote link.